# Serialize class that contains multiple lists and implements IList

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to serialize a C# class that implements `IList` interface. This class maintains two lists, say `list1` and `list2`. I have an enumerator over list1 so that others can use the object of this class to enumerate over `list1` and not care about `list2`. Here is an example:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    public class TestClass : IList
    {

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        //[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "dndil1")]
        public List<CustomVO> List1 { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        //[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "dndil2")]
        public List<CustomVO> List2 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return List1.GetEnumerator();
        }

        // Other methods from IList interface
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to convert this class to json, the serializer ignores `List2` and only serializes `List1`. Then I checked to see if the GetEnumerator was the cause of this issue and found that it indeed was.

I want both lists to be serialized. I do not want to remove the Enumerator. How to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Deserializing an IEnumerable<T> with `[DataContract]` applied does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35778811/3744182).

Comment: I would strongly recommend reconsidering your object model, to determine whether it really makes sense for your class to implement IList. That's a big code smell to me.

Comment: The idea is to have a class that contains a list and keep track of the removed items(thereby another list). This is done so that users can leverage all the nice functions provided by IList while not bothered about the internals of class.