# JsonNet favors IEnumerable over ISerializable

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a class that is a *wrapper* over a string providing some additional functionality. Among other interfaces it also implements the `IEnumerable<char>` interface.

I'd like to be able to serialize it to a string with *JsonNet*. Because it didn't work and always serialized into an array - I guess because of the `IEnumerable<char>` interface, I added the `ISerializable` interface. But for some reason *JsonNet* still creates an array and ignores `ISerializable`. Adding the `SerializableAttribute` didn't help either.

Here's a small proof of concept code that demonstrates the behaviour (for LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotACollection("foo")).Dump(); // ["f","o","o"]
}

[Serializable]
class NotACollection : IEnumerable<char>, ISerializable
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public NotACollection(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _value.GetEnumerator();
    }   

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("_value", _value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

I know I could create a custom `JsonCovert` class but since the wrapper is in a library where I don't want to reference *JsonNet*, I'd prefer another solution.

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought *JsonNet* would pick the `ISerializable` implementation if it's available?

(this class must not implement an implicit conversion to a string because this would defeat its purpose and result in weird bugs)

Comment: Only `BinaryFormatter` uses `Serializable` attribute and `ISerializable` interface. They mean nothing to json.net.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov mhmm... but it looks like it should, see [ISerializable](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable) - _Types that implement ISerializable are serialized as JSON objects. When serializing, only the values returned from ISerializable.GetObjectData are used; members on the type are ignored. When deserializing, the constructor with a SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is called, passing the JSON object's values_

Comment: Hmm, I was wrong.

Comment: In the next release of Json.NET you should be able to use data contract attributes to override the `IEnumerable` attribute.  See [Deserializing an `IEnumerable<T>` with `[DataContract]` applied does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35778811/3744182) which notes that it has recently been implemented.

Comment: Oh, I think this is a duplicate: [How to serialize an ISerializable object into SOAP or Json or Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38188639/3744182).  Related github issue: [IEnumerable and ISerializable conflict #1094](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1094).

Comment: @dbc you're right. I didn't see the other question and marked mine as a duplicate now. Thanks for the links, they explain pretty much everything ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you add `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]` attribute for your class you are wanting to serialize, then it should serialize the class field to Json {"_value" : "foo" }

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
    internal class NotACollection : IEnumerable<char>, ISerializable
```

Comment: Ok, then it looks like I need a json.net reference after all.

Comment: @t3chb0t very likely you will. I had the same issue and ended up with the same solution to force to serialize members.